# ddslick selectText not working or appears twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

According to the [plugin documentation](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#options) :

> selectText default value 'Select...' Set default text to display when
>   no option is selected.

And her in the code snippet below i have used `selectText` but it's not appearing

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#demo-htmlselect').ddslick({
   selectText: "Select your favorite social network",
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://sumankc.com/ddslick/jquery.ddslick.min.js"></script>
<select id="demo-htmlselect">
    <option data-description="Description with Facebook" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png" value="0">Facebook</option>
    <option data-description="Description with Twitter" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png" value="1">Twitter</option>
    <option data-description="Description with LinkedIn" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/linkedin-icon-32.png" value="2">LinkedIn</option>
    <option data-description="Description with Foursquare" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/foursquare-icon-32.png" value="3">Foursquare</option>
</select>
```

Then, i tried with an option field at first to show select text, and now it appears twice in the dropdown

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#demo-htmlselect').ddslick({
   selectText: "Select your favorite social network",
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://sumankc.com/ddslick/jquery.ddslick.min.js"></script>
<select id="demo-htmlselect">
    <option>Select your favourite network</option>
    <option data-description="Description with Facebook" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png" value="0">Facebook</option>
    <option data-description="Description with Twitter" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png" value="1">Twitter</option>
    <option data-description="Description with LinkedIn" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/linkedin-icon-32.png" value="2">LinkedIn</option>
    <option data-description="Description with Foursquare" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/foursquare-icon-32.png" value="3">Foursquare</option>
</select>
```

How can i achieve the single selectText at initial ?

Answer (score 1):

Not to sound snarky but...

According to the plugin documentation :

> Create an empty placeholder for the custom drop down: eg:

```
<div id="myDropdown"></div>
```

Use a `div` instead of a `select`, it'll work.

---

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#demo-htmlselect').ddslick({
   selectText: "Select your favorite social network",
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://sumankc.com/ddslick/jquery.ddslick.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo-htmlselect">
    <option data-description="Description with Facebook" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png" value="0">Facebook</option>
    <option data-description="Description with Twitter" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png" value="1">Twitter</option>
    <option data-description="Description with LinkedIn" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/linkedin-icon-32.png" value="2">LinkedIn</option>
    <option data-description="Description with Foursquare" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/foursquare-icon-32.png" value="3">Foursquare</option>
</div>
```

Comment: i guess that is when you are populating options with json data. please see the section **How to use with HTML <select> and <option>** on documentation